# Does the multiplicative group $\mathbb Z_p^{\times}$, $p$ a prime number, have a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know $\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z_p$ is not a field and I'm guessing there isn't a subgroup in  $\mathbb Z_p^{\times}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z_p$, due to the non-uniqueness of elements in $\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z_p$. But, I'm drawing a blank as to how to write it down in a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, note that the unit group has size $p-1$, whereas $\mathbb Z_p^2$ has size $p^2$, and $p^2>p-1$.

Comment: I just realized this myself as well, but can you explain to me why it is p-1 instead of p elements? Is it because x^p - 1 has p solutions?

Comment: One of the $p$ field elements is zero, and that is not invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

== A **finite** subgroup of the multiplicative group of *any* field is cyclic.

== **All** the subgroups of a cyclic group are cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

There is a (very useful) theorem that any finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic. So $Z_p\times Z_p$ cannot be a subgroup.

Comment: I do know that, but I was of the perception that Zp x Zp is cyclic, the elements in it eventually repeat, since it is the group of integer pairs mod p.

Comment: @confused: that is not correct. A cyclic group has a very specific kind of repetition: you can get all elements of the group by repeating the group operation on **one** element. In your case, you can't get all of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ by repeatedly adding one element to itself.

Comment: Huh, okay, really need to review my definitions!